# Azure Data Factory - optimal design for an IOT pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on an Azure Data Factory solution to solve the following scenario:

1. Data files in CSV format are dumped into Data Lake Gen 2 paths.  There are two varieties of files, let's call them `TypeA` and `TypeB` and each is dumped into a path reflecting a grouping of sensors and the date.

For example:

```
/mycontainer/csv/Group1-20210729-1130/TypeA.csv
/mycontainer/csv/Group1-20210729-1130/TypeB.csv
/mycontainer/csv/Group1-20210729-1138/TypeA.csv
/mycontainer/csv/Group1-20210729-1138/TypeB.csv
```

2. I need to extract data from `TypeA` files in Delta format into a different location on Data Lake Gen 2 storage. I'll need to do similar processing for `TypeB` files but they'll have a different format.

I have successfully put together a "Data Flow" which, given a specific blob path, accomplishes step 2.  But I am struggling to put together a pipeline which applies this for each file which comes in.

My first thought was to do this based on a storage event trigger, whereby each time a CSV file appeared the pipeline would be run to process that one file. I was *almost* able to accomplish this using a combination of `fileName` and `folderPath` parameters and wildcards. I even had a pipeline which will work when triggered manually (meaning I entered a specific `fileName` and `folderPath` value manually). However I had two problems which made me question whether this was the correct approach:

a) I wasn't able to get it to work when triggered by real storage events, I suspect because my combination of parameters and wildcards was ending up including the container name twice in the path it was generating.  It's hard to check this because the error message you get doesn't tell you what the various values actually resolve to (!).

b) The cluster that is needed to extract the CSV into parquet Delta and put the results into Data Lake takes several minutes to spin up - not great if working at the file level. (I realize I can mitigate this somewhat - at a cost - by setting a TTL on the cluster.)

So then I abandoned this approach and tried to set up a pipeline which will be triggered periodically, and will pick up all the CSV files matching a particular pattern (e.g. `/mycontainer/csv/*/TypeA.csv`), process them as a batch, then delete them. At this point I was very surprised to find out that the "Delimited Text" dataset doesn't seem to support wildcards, which is what I was kind of relying on to achieve this in a simple way.

So my questions are:

- Am I broadly on the right track with my 'batch of files' approach? Is there a way to define a delimited text data source which reads its data from multiple blobs?
- Or do I need a more 'iterative' approach using maybe a 'Foreach' step? I'm really really hoping this isn't the case as it seems an odd pattern to be adopting in 2021.
- A much wider question: is ADF a suitable tool for this kind of scenario? I was excited about using it at first, but increasingly it feels like one of those 'exciting to demo but hard to actually use' things which so often pop-up in the low/no code space. Are there popular alternatives which will work nicely with Azure storage?

Any pointers very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're very much on the right track.

Last week I was able to get wildcard CSV's to be imported if the wildcard is in the CSV name. Maybe create an intermediate step to put all Type A's in the same folder?

Concerning ADF - it's a cool technology, with a steep learning curve (and a lot of updates - incl. breaking changes sometimes) if you're looking to get data ingested without too much coding. Some drawbacks:

- Monitoring - if you want to have it cheaper, there's a lot of hacking (e.g. mailing via Logic Apps)
- Debugging - as you've noticed, debug messages are often cryptic or insufficient
- Multiple monthly updates make it feel like a beta. Indeed, often there are straightforward tasks that are quite difficult to achieve.

Good luck ;)